# Very Serious Keyboard App Bug - Shortcuts Disabled

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I am running EOS 5.1 in VirtualBox (also has it on a Laptop but I usually use VirtualBox to test upgrades before applying to Laptop).

See Keyboard -> Shortcuts have valid values before update:

[image]

I checked App Center there was a Keyboard 2.3.6 update.  I clicked Update.

[image]

Immediately afterwards, Keyboard -> Shortcuts are completely Disabled.  No way to re-enable them!

[image]

Is this happening only to VirtualBox VM?

If this happens to bare metal it would be a very serious problem.

Comment: This bug is still affecting me on elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera on October 27th, 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Found issue reported at:

https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-keyboard/issues/317

I will follow the issue at github.

This post can be treated as Answered.